# importing ERROR: importing 'simtk.openmm' is deprecated. import 'openmm' instead

Tags: python, conda

I am running a program 'MSMBuilder', it works well on the last week but suddenly an error came out, saying 'importing 'simtk.openmm' is deprecated. import 'openmm' instead'.
But there is no command such as 'import simtk.openmm' in my code.
Where this error came from?

Here is my code..

```
from msmbuilder.io import gather_metadata, save_meta, NumberedRunsParser

##Construct and save the dataframe
parser= NumberedRunsParser(
      traj_fmt="trajectory-{run}.xtc",
      top_fn="top.pdb",
      step_ps=50,
)
meta = gather_metadata("trajs/*.xtc", parser)
save_meta(meta)
```

Comment: Please add version information about the packages installed.

Comment: Presumably, the package code loads it.